# "instance member cannot be used on type" error on Swift 4 with nested classes

Tags: swift, inner-classes, swift4

I have a class with a nested class. I'm trying to access variables of the outer class from within the nested class:

```
class Thing{
    var name : String?
    var t = Thong()

    class Thong{
        func printMe(){
            print(name) // error: instance member 'name' cannot be used on type 'Thing'
        }
    }

}
```

This however, gives me the following error:

> instance member 'name' cannot be used on type 'Thing'

Is there an elegant way to circumvent this? I was hoping for nested classes to capture the lexical scope, as closures do.

Thanks

Comment: unlike Java Swift nested classes don't automatically have a reference to the outer class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could do something like this

```
class Thing{
    var name : String = "hello world"
    var t = Thong()

    init() {
        t.thing = self
        t.printMe()
    }


    class Thong{
        weak var thing: Thing!

        func printMe(){
            print(thing.name)
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I think you meant to do `var t = Thong(t: self)`

Comment: @CharlesFisher sorry about that. Updated the answer

Comment: What a references circle ! Don't forget to set to nil the `thing` when you don't need it anymore to able to deinit both objects.

Comment: @Thibault No nil-setting needed. There is no strong reference cycle with `weak var thing: ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Try passing in the variable instead of trying to use it directly.

```
class Thing{
    var name : String?
    var t = Thong()

    class Thong{
        func printMe(name: String){
            print(name) 
        }
    }
}
```